# How to get the version name/code on server side using PHP

Tags: php, android

One of my previous versions is now not supported by the back-end. So, I want to get the version code/name of the application that calls the server, so that the server can respond accordingly.

In later version I will use a header to achieve this. Like this:

```
httppost = new HttpPost(url);
httppost.setHeader("version", "10");
```

But any way to get the version on server side without setting a header, just from the apk's manifest.

I am using `PHP` at back-end.

Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately not,

HttpPost is designed to have only the headers and data you supply it doesn't add anything automatically.

You can add that header in the new version and in case the header is missing (When checking from your server side PHP script) then deny the access or ask the user to install the new version.